# Schedule Post for Questions

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have noticed that the Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange is very active when I am asleep and barely active when I am awake. Is there a schedule send feature so that I could post my questions at a certain time to gain more attention to the question?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such feature, since *it wouldn't have any effect*. There is a short Help Center article [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) which may or may not help you in this case, but posting it at a different time would have no effect. When you're awake, there may be less visitors, but there are also *less new questions* competing for attention, and both effects cancel each other out.

I've done some research a while ago on [Stack Overflow question views](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173), of which the conclusion was

> The number of views for a question is independent from the moment of posting.

On Music.SE we have less data to work with, so I [modified the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1238801/question-views-by-posting-time?StartDate=2016-01-01&EndDate=2020-05-01#graph) a bit:

[image]

The horizontal axis is the 'hour of the week' - due to SQL Server peculiarities it starts counting at 24. You see the daily peaks in the number of questions around 18:00 UTC; note that there's no such pattern in the number of views.

Finally, even if such a tool *would* exist, it has the disadvantage of not being able to react to comments/answers soon, which might be necessary to improve your question.